# passing 2 directories in 1 fs.readdirSync()

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, console, readdir

I've been on this problem for a while and I can't figure it out, I am trying to make my `readdirSync` to recognize the `SlashCommands, MessageCommmands` directory but I can't figure it out.

- **File Structure**

```
Commands
┣ MessageCommands
┃ ┣ Economy
┃ ┃ ┣ balance.js
┃ ┃ ┣ login.js
┃ ┃ ┣ recoveraccount.js
┃ ┃ ┣ signout.js
┃ ┃ ┗ signup.js
┃ ┗ Utility
┃ ┃ ┣ ping.js
┃ ┃ ┗ setprefix.js
┗ SlashCommands
┃ ┣ Info
┃ ┃ ┗ info.js
┃ ┗ Test
┃ ┃ ┗ test.js
```

- **What I** ***WAS* Getting**

```
.------------------------------------------------------.
|                       Commands                       |
|------------------------------------------------------|
| Category |      Command      |      Load status      |
|----------|-------------------|-----------------------|
| Economy  | balance.js        | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Economy  | login.js          | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Economy  | recoveraccount.js | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Economy  | signout.js        | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Economy  | signup.js         | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Test     | guildname.js      | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Test     | howlong.js        | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Utility  | ping.js           | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| Utility  | setprefix.js      | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
'------------------------------------------------------'
```

- **Code**

```js
const { readdirSync } = require('fs');
const ascii = require('ascii-table');
let table = new ascii("Commands");
table.setHeading('Command Type', 'Category', 'Command', ' Load status');

module.exports = (client) => {
    readdirSync('./Commands/').forEach(type, dir => {
        let commands = readdirSync(`./Commands/${type}/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
        for (let file of commands) {
            let pull = require(`../Commands/${type}/${dir}/${file}`);
            if (pull.name) {
                client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
                table.addRow(type, dir, file, '✔️  -> Command Loaded')
            } else {
                table.addRow(type, dir, file, '❌  -> Command Error')
                continue;
            } if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))
        }
    });
    console.log(table.toString());
    console.log(`[Command] Command Handler is Ready! | Total Commands: ${client.commands.size}`)
}
```

- **What *I'M* Expecting**

```
.------------------------------------------------------------------------.
|                               Commands                                 |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   Command Type  | Category |      Command      |      Load status      |
|-----------------|----------|-------------------|-----------------------|
| MessageCommands | Economy  | balance.js        | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| MessageCommands | Economy  | login.js          | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| MessageCommands | Economy  | recoveraccount.js | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| MessageCommands | Economy  | signout.js        | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| MessageCommands | Economy  | signup.js         | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| MessageCommands | Utility  | ping.js           | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
| MessageCommands | Utility  | setprefix.js      | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
|  SlashCommands  |  Info    | info.js           | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
|  SlashCommands  |  Test    | test.js           | ✔️  -> Command Loaded |
'------------------------------------------------------------------------'
```

Comment: if you have questions about my question, just comment here, thanks!!

Comment: I suggest creating objects with the appropriate properties, adding them to an array, then use the [`console.table` command](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoletabletabulardata-properties) to print it. I don't know anything about this `ascii-table` library, as `console.table` does everything I need.

Comment: im sorry but, can you instead re-do my command? this way i can learn more about it(I learn better reading codes)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that should work, but I didn't feel like creating the directory structure to validate it, so do try it out in your environment.

```js
const {
  readdirSync
} = require('fs');

const table = [];

module.exports = (client) => {
  readdirSync('./Commands/').forEach(type, dir => {
    let commands = readdirSync(`./Commands/${type}/${dir}/`).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (let file of commands) {
      let pull = require(`../Commands/${type}/${dir}/${file}`);
      if (pull.name) {
        client.commands.set(pull.name, pull);
        table.push({
          'Command Type': type,
          Category: dir,
          Command: file,
          'Load status': '✔️  -> Command Loaded'
        });
      } else {
        table.push({
          'Command Type': type,
          Category: dir,
          Command: file,
          'Load status': '❌  -> Command Error'
        });
        continue;
      }
      if (pull.aliases && Array.isArray(pull.aliases)) pull.aliases.forEach(alias => client.aliases.set(alias, pull.name))
    }
  });
  console.table(table);
  console.log(`[Command] Command Handler is Ready! | Total Commands: ${client.commands.size}`)
}
```

Comment: hello, i tried this code but it gave me an error `ReferenceError: type is not defined`, but when i defined the type using `let type;`, it gave me an `"TypeError: undefined is not a function"`.

Comment: i even tried putting the `"MessageCommands" and "SlashCommands"` in array but it still doesnt work